# create a new database programmatically using python and the db.py library

Tags: python, pandas, mariadb

Rather than connecting to an existing database created using mariadb command line I would like to know if it is possible to create a new mariadb database using python library db.py [db.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/db.py)

Comment: did you try.. `query = db.query("create database something;")`

Comment: I don't think you can create a database with db.py (you need to connect to one to query it), but you can always shell out...

Comment: @AndyHayden can you create the database with a library other than db.py maybe https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1